# How I can emit Hair particles In arranged ( Grid ) Way?

Tags: particles

I want my hair particles **Not To Be** Placed in a randomly places as default In Blender but, To be placed in arranged Way (Form) .

Here Is My Problem  :

[image]

If know how To Solve this Problem
So Please tell me.**THANKS**

Comment: Enable the **Advanced** options, then deselect "Random", and enable "Even Distribution"

Comment: Actually When I Enabled Advanced Options Even Distribution Was Already Enabled And When I Disabled Random Nothing Happened.But When I Disabled Even Distribution It Became Organized But Not In The Way I Wanted it was Placed In A Triangle Shaped Path  .Thank You Any Way.

Comment: Sub-divide your mesh and reduce the amount of particles to see the effect. You can put a particle on every face or vertex if you choose.

Comment: I subdivided my plane and decreased the amount of the particles but it didn't seem to be different. So can you show Me the Way of  putting a particle on every face or vertex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select  the vertices of your subdivided mesh and make them a vertex group
2. Set a particle system and select Vertex as the emitter.
3. Add the group in the system's Vertex Groups section (Density field, at the top)

Maybe it works.

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot ... so that it is easier for any one who is new in blender ?